# How to change attribute value of specific XAML tag wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have converted SVG image into XAML using SharpVector which created this following code:

```
<DrawingGroup>
<DrawingGroup x:Name="DrawingLayer">
   <DrawingGroup x:Name="Rooms">
      <Drawing Group>
      ..
      </DrawingGroup>
      ..
      ..
  </DrawingGroup>
 <DrawingGroup x:Name="Paths">
    <GeometryDrawing>
    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
      <Pen Brush="#FF0000FF" Thickness="1"StartLineCap="Flat"EndLineCap="Flat" LineJoin="Miter" opacity="1" />
    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
      <LineGeometry StartPoint="378,45" EndPoint="378,98" />
    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
  </GeometryDrawing>
   <GeometryDrawing> ..</GeometryDrawing>
   </GeometryDrawing> .. </GeometryDrawing>
</DrawingGroup>
```

what i want is to search for DrawingGroup tag whose attribute value x:Name="paths" then do changes in `<pen opacity="0" other..attributes>`
i am loading this xaml file at load time.
i am totally confuse with this file ..

Answer (score 0):

You can just put an x:Name on the element itself, no need to search for the DrawingGroup x:Name

```
<Pen Brush="#FF0000FF" Thickness="1" StartLineCap="Flat" EndLineCap="Flat" LineJoin="Miter" x:Name="Pen1"/>
```

and edit it from CodeBehind:

```
Pen1.Thickness = 100;
```

EDIT: Since you're getting the XAML during runtime:

```
 ((GeometryDrawing)Paths.Children[0]).Pen.Thickness = 100;
```

Comment: i am loading this xaml at runtime thats the problem

Comment: Paths does not exists in the currrent context.

Comment: How are you loading the XAML at runtime @tabby ?

Comment: i am using SvgVector library from Nuget that convert svg files and load xaml file @Tyress